# Date Time Issue

Tags: c#

the data table (C#) returns date/time (with AM/PM) column with below data,

08/01/2011 5:16:02 PM
07/27/2011 9:31:26 PM

how to convert the same to string data type in C#?

in SQL, i can convert datetime to string by below, but how to convert in C#....?

```
ISNULL(CASE WHEN CONVERT(CHAR(10),FirstCommunicationDate,108)<'12:00:00'  THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),FirstCommunicationDate,101)+ SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),FirstCommunicationDate,109),12,15) + ' AM'
            ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),FirstCommunicationDate,101)+ SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),FirstCommunicationDate,109),12,15) + ' PM' END, '') AS FirstCommunicationDate
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DateTime.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) Method for this Purpose.

Comment: specifically `ToString("g")` or `ToString("G")`

Comment: @Eric, about what you are asking?

Comment: I meant that he could use `DateTime.ToString("g")` to get the output he's looking for.

Comment: @Eric Falsken ya, you are correct in his case he should use that